# What are the children() and parent() methods of Yii ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2, parent, children

I am working on the web-store-app created with Yii and can not find anything about `children()` and `parent()` methods of `ActiveRecord` objects in the documentation.

As I understand it somehow depends on certain fields in tabels but I can not find any relations. Can you guide my about this ones, please.

```php
$brands = Category::findOne(['slug' => $slug])->children()->all();
$products = Category::findByRoute(['path' => $path])->parent()->one();
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `children()` or `parent()` in Yii, these are probably custom methods created in this "web-store-app". You should check documentation of this system (or look through its source code).

Comment: what i suspect that you are using a `Nested Set Model` and might be using some kind of extension with the model can you show which class is `Category` model extending from ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are three tables, Products, ProductCategory & Order.

The Product belongs to a single category so define below relation with BELONGS_TO in the Product model.
while Product belongs to multiple order so define blow relation with HAS_MANY in the product model.

```
public function relations() {
      return array(
           'rel_category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProductCategory', 'pro_cat_id'),
           'rel_order' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Order', 'product_id'),
      );
}
```

Now fetch product with category and orders using a single command.

For All products

```
$model = Product::model()->findAll();
```

For Single Product

```
$model = Product::model()->findByPK(1);
```

You can access the Product category with below syntax

```
echo $model->rel_category[title];
foreach($model->rel_order as $order):
   echo $order->id;
endforeach;
```

The same thing can be done in ProductCategory & Order Model. You just have to define the proper relation in the model.

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($model); exit(); // this will print whole model for you.
```